# How to implement session timeout - Angular - Django app integration with Azure AD

Tags: javascript, django, angular, session, azure-active-directory

Overview - I am working on a solution having UI built in angular and backend in django. I want to implement authentication and authorization using Azure AD. At UI, I have made use of @azure/msal-angular, which acquires access tokens directly from azure each time a backend enpoint is hit.

Problem 1 - Access tokens are acquired in the background and never expire unless user logs out. Is there a way to log user out after certain period of time/inactivity?

Problem 2 - @azure/msal-angular uses implicit grant flow which receives user tokens in url fragments, which seems not secure. Is auth code a better way to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Access tokens are acquired in the background and never expire unless
> user logs out. Is there a way to log user out after certain period of
> time/inactivity?

You could [change TokenLifetimePolicy of the token lifetime defaults](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/registration-config-change-token-lifetime-how-to). For the full documentation, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#token-types). Follow the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46853376/13308381) to create and set the Token Lifetime Policy.

> @azure/msal-angular uses implicit grant flow which receives user
> tokens in url fragments, which seems not secure. Is auth code a better
> way to go about it?

Yes, [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) is better. As the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow) shows, "There are a few important security considerations to take into account when using the implicit flow specifically around client and user impersonation". Auth code flow enables apps to securely acquire access_tokens that can be used to access resources secured by the Microsoft identity platform endpoint, as well as refresh tokens to get additional access_tokens and ID tokens for the signed-in user. You could use auth code flow with PKCE, this is the [sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-browser).